# Read xml Node Values In Php

Tags: php, xml

```
<root>
<status>Call Triggered Successfully</status>
<is_ndnc>no</is_ndnc>
<callid>aaac5814-400f-45ea-9235-f0198e5edd4b</callid>
</root>
```

how can Read nodes i hv to assign to variable
like

```
$status='Call Triggered Successfully';
$is_ndnc='no';
$callid='aaac5814-400f-45ea-9235-f0198e5edd4b';
```

Comment: There are numerous ways to parse/read XML via PHP. Let your fingers do the searching.

Comment: @rahul Do not put your solution in your question. You can enter and answer just like everybody else. You can even mark it as the correct answer after 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways in which you can gt the nodevalue from xml in php.

You could use [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) which returns an array of SimpleXMLElement objects.

Or you could load the file with `simplexml_load_file()` and use the foreach loop as explained [here](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-XML-Retrieving-Node-Values-P410.html)